# input field doesnt clear on single click of delete button, only double

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, react-typescript

I am using formik and I have a textfield where user inputs SSN number. I have a function handling the format of SSN number to something like this 000-00-0000. I call this function in my onChange and this works well. But the problem is when i try to clear the input field, it takes two clicks to delete one number

```
const [ssn, setSsn] = useState('');
```

```
const normalizeInput = (value: any, previousValue: any) => {
    // return nothing if no value
    if (!value) return value;

    // only allows 0-9 inputs
    const currentValue = value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
    const cvLength = currentValue.length;

    if (!previousValue || value.length > previousValue.length) {
      // returns: "1", "12", "123"
      if (cvLength < 4) return currentValue;
      // returns: "123", "123-4", "123-45",
      if (cvLength < 7) return `${currentValue.slice(0, 3)}-${currentValue.slice(3)}`;
      // returns: "123-45-", "123-45-6", "123-45-67", "123-45-678", "123-45-6789"
      return `${currentValue.slice(0, 3)}-${currentValue.slice(3, 5)}-${currentValue.slice(5, 9)}`;
    }
  };
```

```
<form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
          <TextField
            name="ssn"
            id="ssn"
            label="SSN*"
            variant="filled"
            value={formik.values.ssn}
            onChange={(e) => {
              setSsn(normalizeInput(e.target.value, ssn));
            }}
          />
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue with the input field not clearing on a single click, you can create a separate clear button and handle the clearing of the input field using a state update. Based on your current code, you can make the following changes:

First, add a clear button to your form:

```
<form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
  <TextField
    name="ssn"
    id="ssn"
    label="SSN*"
    variant="filled"
    value={formik.values.ssn}
    onChange={(e) => {
      setSsn(normalizeInput(e.target.value, ssn));
    }}
  />
  <button type="button" onClick={() => setSsn('')}>
    Clear SSN
  </button>
</form>
```

Notice that the button has a type="button" attribute to prevent it from submitting the form. The onClick event is set to update the ssn state to an empty string, effectively clearing the input field.

Additionally, you need to update the value of the TextField component to be ssn instead of formik.values.ssn:

```
<TextField
  name="ssn"
  id="ssn"
  label="SSN*"
  variant="filled"
  value={ssn}
  onChange={(e) => {
    setSsn(normalizeInput(e.target.value, ssn));
  }}
/>
```

Now, when you click the "Clear SSN" button, the input field should clear on a single click.

Here's the modified code snippet:

```
const [ssn, setSsn] = useState('');

const normalizeInput = (value: any, previousValue: any) => {
  // return nothing if no value
  if (!value) return value;

  // only allows 0-9 inputs
  const currentValue = value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
  const cvLength = currentValue.length;

  if (!previousValue || value.length > previousValue.length) {
    if (cvLength < 4) return currentValue;
    if (cvLength < 7) return `${currentValue.slice(0, 3)}-${currentValue.slice(3)}`;
    return `${currentValue.slice(0, 3)}-${currentValue.slice(3, 5)}-${currentValue.slice(5, 9)}`;
  }
};

<form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
  <TextField
    name="ssn"
    id="ssn"
    label="SSN*"
    variant="filled"
    value={ssn}
    onChange={(e) => {
      setSsn(normalizeInput(e.target.value, ssn));
    }}
  />
  <button type="button" onClick={() => setSsn('')}>
    Clear SSN
  </button>
</form>
```

This should resolve the issue of the input field not clearing on a single click of the delete button.

Comment: Greatly appreciate your input. But I think there’s a confusion. By clicking the delete button I meant backspace. You know, when one tries to undo what he has typed in the input field